# Number guessing game: How can I accept input that says "guess =" before the number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
guess = input("What is your guess?")
answer = random.randint(0,100)

while guess != answer:
    try:
        guess = float(guess)
        if guess > answer:
            print ("Your guess is too high!")
        elif guess < answer:
            print ("Your guess is too low!")
        elif guess == answer:
            print ("Congratulations!")
            break
        guess = input("What is your guess?")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print ("Bad input. Try again!")
        guess = input("What is your guess?")
```

So my code works except that when i enter for example: guess = 30, it seems the input as invalid...how can I make it so it accepts it as a correct guess?

New to python here :)
Thanks.

Comment: When the program prompts you to input a guess, are you literally entering `guess = 30`, or just `30`?

Comment: You should be able to have only one line which takes input, at the top of the while loop.  Set guess = -1 before entering. You may want to use int, not float.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and pasted your code into Python 3.5, and....apart from needing to indent everything after the while statement it worked fine.

Are you inputting just the number: 30

...or "guess = 30"? Because that does cause a problem since it's not a number.
You only need to input the number. :)

If you want to accept "guess = 30" then:

```
import random
import re ###<-Add this

guess = input("What is your guess?")
answer = random.randint(0,100)

while guess != answer:
    try:
        guess = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", guess) ###<- Add this
        guess = float(guess)
        if guess > answer:
            print ("Your guess is too high!")
        elif guess < answer:
            print ("Your guess is too low!")
        elif guess == answer:
            print ("Congratulations!")
            break
        guess = input("What is your guess?")
        continue
    except ValueError:
        print ("Bad input. Try again!")
        guess = input("What is your guess?")
```

These two lines will use Regular Expressions to strip the input of any non numeric characters before processing.

Comment: Hey, yeah I should indent after the while statement, but like this is practice for my class and one of the challenge questions was to make sure that special case would work XD It's not needed, I guess. This whole thing took me about an hour to complete. Hopefully that's not too slow.

Comment: If you really want it to accept "guess = 30" you can use : import re then use: guess = re.sub("[^0-9]", "", guess) to remove non-numeric characters from the input.

Comment: Well I never learned that....so idk what my teacher was expecting? She said she wanted us to master try and except and break, continue, etc.

Comment: I think your use of try/catch is good. It already catches bad input without crashing so no problem. Good code.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how much you have learnt in that class, but adding the following line should allow you to accept both `30` and `guess = 30` (or even `foo=bar=30`):

```
...
while guess != answer:
    guess = guess.split('=')[-1]    # Add this line
    try:
        guess = float(guess)
        ...
```

It simply splits the input using `=` as a delimiter and only uses the last part (`[-1]`).

Answer (score 0):

So I reordered your code:

- I narrowed `try/except` down to just the line which can cause the ValueError, because that makes it clear what particular error this `except` block is trying to handle - puts the error handling near the source of the error. This also makes a good reason to have `continue` because it now skips the "too high/too low" code, instead of in your code it does nothing.
- I changed the `while` loop condition so it says `while True:` to make it an infinite loop. In your code, `while guess != answer` implies that it will break when the guess is correct, you actually use `break` to exit the loop, so that is misleading. It would be sensible to use `while guess != answer` and not have `break` anywhere, but if you have to use `break` as part of the assignment then my code has some 'reason' to use it (breaking an infinite loop).
- I moved the `guess = input(...)` code inside the loop only, because it doesn't need to be duplicated at the top or inside the error handling. (Imagine if you had to change the text, 3 places is more annoying than 1 place).
- There are lots of ways to handle the `guess = 30` input. You could literally handle that, and only that, by looking for `if "guess = " in guess:` and then if that text matches, use `guess = guess.replace("guess = ", "")` to replace it away, leaving just the number. Or use regular expressions, as another answer has used to drop text and leave digits, or use string `split()`, as yet another answer has. My answer here has `filter()` which filters something using a test - in this case it tests if something is a number, and only allows numbers through, so it drops all the text. Same as the regex is doing, really, just a different approach.

code:

```
import random

answer = random.randint(0,100)

while True:
    guess = input("What is your guess?")

    # filters out only the numbers
    # and makes them into a string, e.g.
    # 1) "guess = 30"
    # 2) [3,0]
    # 3) "30"
    guess = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, guess))

    try:
        guess = float(guess)
    except ValueError:
        print ("Bad input. Try again!")
        continue

    if guess > answer:
        print ("Your guess is too high!")
    elif guess < answer:
        print ("Your guess is too low!")
    else:
        print ("Congratulations!")
        break
```

[Try it online at repl.it](https://repl.it/D80v/1)

Comment: Hi. Thanks!!!!! If I wrote it my way, would that be considered bad code? I didn't do the filter method because I didn't learn it.

Comment: @XVocalz Not bad at all, no (in my opinion). It's neat and tidy, you have variable names which make sense ("guess" instead of "x"), you use `random.randint()` by the full name, you have error handling so it doesn't just crash out, it will work(!), they're all good things. I'm mostly just playing around - there's tons of ways of writing code and never really a right way, and an endless amount of things that "could maybe be a bit better".